# Kendo UI dropdown loosing state

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui

I have 2 Kendo UI Web drop downs, one is binding on client side and one is having static value:

```
<select runat="server" id="ddlCheckStatic" class="k-dropdown" style="width: auto">
   <option value="One">One</option>
   <option value="Two">Two</option>
   <option value="Three">Three</option>
</select>
<select runat="server" id="ddlCheckdynamic" class="k-dropdown" style="width: auto">
</select>

<script>
 $("#ddlCheckStatic").kendoDropDownList();

 var data =
    [
      { text: "Black", Id: "1" },
      { text: "Orange", Id: "2" },
      { text: "Grey", Id: "3" }
    ];

  $("#ddlCheck").kendoDropDownList({
    dataValueField: "Id",
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataSource: data
  });
</script>
```

There's one asp.net button to make a postback

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" 
  Text="Server Button" CssClass="k-button" OnClick="btn_Click" />
```

On Server side Click of which I'm getting selected values of drop downs.

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string _static = ddlCheckStatic.Value; // Working great :)
  string _dynamic = ddlCheckdynamic.Value; // Is blank everytime :(
}
```

Now the static drop down i.e. **ddlCheckStatic** is maintaining it's state on postbacks and it's selected value is also accessible in **btn_Click** but the same thing is not happening for dynamic one i.e. **ddlCheckdynamic**.
Is there anyway to get the same behavior from dynamic one also?

### Update

If values are bound from server side like below, then control is maintaining it's state.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
     ddlCheckDynamic.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem() { Text = "Black", Value = "1" });
     ddlCheckDynamic.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem() { Text = "Orange", Value = "2" });
     ddlCheckDynamic.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem() { Text = "Grey", Value = "3" });
   }
}
```

Comment: You can't access from server-side to items generated from client-side because when items are added to select, ASPNET is not notified of this and proper .Net HTML tag aren't present.

Comment: Yes, I also got to know that it is the problem I'm having. But is there any solution for this in Kendo?

Comment: I think that the only way to retrieve the selected value from the dropdown is to use javascript : when the value is selected you set a hidden field and then retrieve it server-side.